# slide (animation) not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with small buttons (more then just only 2) for profiles. All is working more or less fine, except hide and show (slideToggle) - my div (profilePannel) appears without nice slow expand, just suddently.

Only css element (margin-bottom) is working fine. To see it, you may click profile one, then see on the second button, final effect.

**jQuery**

```
var menu;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.img').click(function () {
        menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));
        $(".profilePannel:not(#" + menu.attr("id") + ")").slideUp("slow");
        menu.slideToggle("slow");
    });
})
```

[Try it!](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Lk/)

Can anyone be so nice and tell me why, and how I can change it?

And BTW, I have a trouble with positioning my profilePanel - I wish to show it just under each profile button, without moving rest of buttons. I have tried with position: relative, absolute, also with z-index but I have missed something and dont have the output that I wish.

Comment: some addition in @oGeez answer for your 2nd problem http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Lk/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be your `min-height` causing you issues. If you remove/change that, you get the effect you are going for:

```
.profilePannel {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: silver;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    opacity: 0.75;
    -moz-opacity:0.75;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Also, you can better write

```
$(".profilePannel:not(#" + menu.attr("id") + ")").slideUp("slow");
```

As:

```
$(".profilePannel").not(menu).slideUp("slow");
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Lk/5/)

If you really want to use `min-height` you'd need to come up with an alternative - or just put it in a container and set the `min-height` on that:

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Lk/6/)

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right! That was the problem. Thank you very much. Can you also help me with profilePannel to put above rest of the buttons, without moving them (wright now, if you have more buttons, all buttons are move to make space for this div). Something like attribute title..

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask another question (:

Answer (score 0):

Here all is correctly working including absolute po
Try [`this`](http://jsfiddle.net/DR5Lk/3/) out

JavaScript code:

```
var menu;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.profilePannel').each(function(obj){
        $(this).height( $(this).height() );
        $(this).css('min-height', 0);
    })

    $('.img').click(function () {
            menu = $("#" + $(this).data("menu"));

            menu.slideDown().siblings('.profilePannel').slideUp();


        });

})
```